# Natural conditions for existence of sections of $g_n:\pi_n(\Omega_0(X,A)) \to \pi_n(A\times A)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology

Let $\Omega_0(X,A)$ denote the (component of the constant paths on $A$ of the) space of paths with endpoints on $A$, where $X$ and $A$ are path-connected. There is a map $\Omega_0(X,A) \to A \times A$ which is just the evaluation at the endpoints, and thus we get maps
$$g_n: \pi_n(\Omega_0(X,A)) \to \pi_{n}(A \times A).$$
Are there natural conditions that can be imposed upon $X,A$ and perhaps $n$ such that the above map admits a section, i.e. a map $s_n: \pi_n(A\times A) \to \pi_n(\Omega_0(X,A))$ such that $g_n \circ s_n =1$? I'm particularly interested in the cases $n=1,2$.

An idea would be to try to "force through" a section via a map $s:A \times A \to \Omega_0(X,A)$ that takes $(p,q)$ into a path that connects $p$ to $q$, but this is obviously not even well-defined to begin with. However, this idea seems to suggest that maybe some conditions can be related to imposing that, given a certain $n$, some of the maps $\pi_i(A) \to \pi_i(X)$ induced by the inclusion vanish. In any case, if "natural conditions" is somewhat unclear, then consider it "conditions on the maps induced by the inclusion $i:A \to X$", although I appreciate other situations which may come up.

Comment: If you knew $A$ was a convex subset of a vector space, you could lift $(P,Q)\mapsto \gamma(t)= tQ+(1-t)P$. But that seems too restrictive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignoring path components, the homotopy fibre of $\Omega(X,A)\rightarrow A\times A$ is equivalent to $\Omega X$. Thus there is a fibration sequence
$$\dots\rightarrow\Omega(\Omega(X,A))\xrightarrow{\Omega e}\Omega A\times \Omega A\xrightarrow{\delta} \Omega X\rightarrow \Omega(X,A)\xrightarrow{e} A\times A$$
where we have identified $\Omega (A\times A)\cong \Omega A\times\Omega A$ in the natural way. It can be shown that the connecting map $\delta$ is homotopic to the sum $\Omega(j\circ pr_1)-\Omega(j\circ pr_2)$, where $j:A\hookrightarrow X$ is the inclusion and the sum is formed using the loop multiplication on $\Omega X$.

Thus, in general, the endpoint evaluation $e$ has no canonical section, even after looping. For instance, if $in_1:A\hookrightarrow A\times A$ is the inclusion into the first factor, then by the above $\delta\circ\Omega(in_1)\simeq\Omega j$, so $\delta$ cannot be null-homotopic unless $\Omega j$ is. Of course a sufficient, but restrictive, condition is that $j$ (or $\Omega j$) be null-homotopic. In this case $\delta\simeq\ast$, so $\Omega(\Omega(X,A))\simeq \Omega A\times\Omega A\times\Omega^2 X$. (Examples: $(X,A)=(D^{n+1},S^n)$, $(X,A)=(S^{n+1},S^n)$)

However, since you are mainly interested in homotopy groups, we do have the following. Under the isomorphisms $\pi_n(\Omega A\times \Omega A)\cong\pi_{n+1}(A)\oplus\pi_{n+1}(A)$ and $\pi_n(\Omega X)\cong\pi_{n+1}(X)$, the homomorphism induced by $\delta$ becomes
$$\delta_*=j_*pr_{1}-j_*pr_{2}:\pi_{n+1}(A)\oplus\pi_{n+1}(A)\rightarrow \pi_{n+1}(X).$$
i.e. $\delta_*(x\oplus y)=j_*x-j_*y.$

In particular, if $j_*:\pi_{n+1}A\rightarrow\pi_{n+1}X$ is the trivial homomorphism, then the map
$$\pi_{n+1}(X)\rightarrow \pi_n(\Omega(X,A))$$
is injective, and
$$\pi_{n+1}(\Omega(X,A))\rightarrow \pi_{n+1}(A)\oplus\pi_{n+1}(A)$$
is surjective. I'm not guaranteeing that this map have a natural splitting, or even a splitting at all. I think it will not in general, even under the assumption on $j_*$ in this degree. Certainly surjectivity is a necessary condition, however. (Example: $(\mathbb{C}P^2,S^2)$. The map $\pi_2S^2\rightarrow\pi_2\mathbb{C}P^2$ is an isomorphism but $\pi_nS^2\rightarrow\pi_n\mathbb{C}P^2$ is trivial when $n\neq2$. Thus $\pi_n\Omega(\mathbb{C}P^2,S^2)\rightarrow\pi_nS^2\oplus\pi_nS^2$ is onto if $n\neq 2$. When $n=2$ it is injective and $\pi_2\Omega(\mathbb{C}P^2,S^2)\cong\mathbb{Z}$.)

Finally I'll comment on the path components. We haven't done anything restrictive in the above, since for instance $\pi_n(\Omega(X,A))=\pi_n(\Omega_0(X,A))$ when $n\geq1$, assuming the basepoint in $\Omega(X,A)$ is the constant loop at the basepoint of $A$.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer. If I understand correctly, there is such a section if the inclusion is null-homotopic. It is restrictive but it seems that it could have good examples for my purposes. But you seem not to be looking directly at the long exact sequence of homotopy groups of the fibration. Is it possible to show directly that the boundary map in that long exact sequence vanishes, and also show the section explicitly, if the inclusion is null-homotopic? I'm not familiar with the point of view of the fibration sequence you mention.

Comment: In the last part (starting 'In particular,...') I've given a necessary and sufficient condition for the boundary map to vanish in some degree. Namely that $j_*$ be zero (the boundary map in the homotopy exact sequence is exactly $\delta_*=j_*pr_1-j_*pr_2=0$. Thus for $\delta_*=0$ it is clearly necessary and sufficient that $j_*=0$). However, I don't see why situations like, for instance, $\pi_n(\Omega(X,A))=\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}$ and $\pi_n(A)\oplus\pi_n(A)=\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus \mathbb{Z}_2$ cannot occur.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Given your last comment and reading again, I think I misunderstood: it appears to be that even if $j$ is null-homotopic then you can't guarantee the existence of a section of $e$. Could you clarify this please? (It is unclear if by " Of course a sufficient, but restrictive, condition (...)" you are just referring to the immediate previous statement or 'Thus, in general, the endpoint evaluation e has no canonical section, even after looping.'."

Comment: Suppose $F:A\rightarrow PX$ is a null-homotopy $F:j\simeq\ast$. Define $s:A\times A\rightarrow \Omega (X,A)$ by sending $(a,b)$ to the path $s(a,b)=F(a)-F(b)$. Then $e\circ s(a,b)=(F(a,0),-F(b,1))=(F(a,0),F(b,0))=(a,b)$.

Comment: By 'Of course..' I am referring to the paragraph directly above the statement. Away from that line I make no assumption that $j$ be null-homotopic. The point is that $j$ being null-homotopic is not detected by its action on homotopy groups. If we assume only that $j_*$ is the zero-homomorphism in degree $n$, then this gives us a surjection $\pi_n(\Omega(X,A))\rightarrow\pi_nA\times\pi_nA\rightarrow 0$. The problem is that arbitrary surjections of abelian groups need not be split.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. It was very helpful. In the case of the inclusion being null-homotopic, does it follow that the sequence splits on the $\pi_1$-level as a *direct* product? It seems to me that the action of $\pi_1(A \times A)$ on $\pi_1(\Omega(X))$ that gives the semi-direct product structure could be trivial (i.e. the identity) in this case, but I don't know.

Comment: What you have written is correct; the $\pi_1$-action is trivial. More generally, let $i:\Omega X\rightarrow\Omega(X,A)$ be the inclusion of the fibre and check that the map $(\Omega A\times \Omega A)\times \Omega^2 X\rightarrow \Omega(\Omega(X,A))$ which is the sum of $\Omega i$ and the section $s$ (as above) is a weak equivalence.